# flutter wrong order init and dispose methods

Tags: flutter

I have question. When we do quik(double click) actions `pop()`from screen and then `push()`to this screen. In this case `dispose()` and `init()`will be in wrong order. I think dispose shoul call first(pop) and then init(push) when we open screen. But actual result => first init and then dispose.How to fix it in flutter?

Comment: Can you share your code so it is easier to understand the context of your question?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same unexpected behaviour.
I tried to create a reproduced code https://github.com/antonio-nicolau/Flutter-beamer-with-flutter_hooks

please see logs and you'll notice dipose being called in reverse mode

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. It would be better if you post it in a comment.

Comment: Not an answer but a comment